# can i perform gzseek to update a file compressed using gzwrite (CPP)?

Tags: c++, compression, zlib, gzip

I have a file written using gzwrite. Now i want to edit this file and insert some data in the middle by seeking. Is this possible with gzseek/gzwrite in cpp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't possible. You have to create a new file by successively writing the pieces.

So it is not much different from inserting data in the middle of an uncompressed file, except for one thing: with the uncompressed file, you could leave a hole of the right size (a series of spaces, for example) and later on overwrite that with the data to be inserted, but of course that is not possible with the compressed file because you cannot predict its compressed length.